# How to make a registration form having different type of inputs (check box & radio button) using Ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to make a registration form having different types of inputs, and insert the data in a database using the Ajax `$.post method`. My HTML code:

index.php

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueru.js"></script> 
        <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() 
            $("#submit").click(function(){ 
                $.post( 
                    "phpindex.php",{ 
                        name:$('#ib1').val(), 
                        mygender:$('#ib2').val(), 
                        mygender:$('#ibi3').val(), 
                        lang1:$('#ib4').val(), 
                        lang2:$('#ib5').val() 
                    }, 
                    function(data){ 
                        $("#mydiv").html(data) 
                    } 
                ) 
            }); 
        )}; 
        </script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <table> 
            name:-<input type=text  name="" id="id1"/><br/> 
            gender:-<input type=radio name="mygender" value="" id="ib2"/>male 
            <input  type=radio name="mygender" value="" id="ib3"/>female<br/> 
            lamguage:-<input  type=checbox name="lang1" value=""  id="ib4"/>hindi 
            <inut type=checkbx    name="lang2" value="" id="ib5"/>nglish 

            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"> 
        </table> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

The problem is that only the name is being inserted, the rest of the data (gender and language) is not inserted into the table. the PHP file reguarding this HTML is below:

phpndex.php

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("mydb"); 
$var1=$_POST['name']; 
$var2=$_POST['mygender']; 
$var3=$_POST['mygender']; 
$var4=$_POST['lang1']; 
$var5=$_POST['lang2']; 
$var6=$var4.$var5; 
$query="insert into mytable4 values('$var1','$var2','$var3','$var6')"; 
$result=mysql_query($query); 
if($result)
{echo"data is inserted";) 
else{echo"data is not inserted";} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have multiple problems.

1) The type attributes for your language checkboxes should be double quoted, the types are misspelled and the values are missing. They should be:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="lang1" value="hindi"  id="ib4"/>hindi
<input type="checkbox" name="lang2" value="english" id="ib5"/>english
```

2) You are probably overwriting the selected value for "mygender" because you are adding it to the post hash twice. To make it work with minimal changes you could edit the post hash declaration to:

```
mygender1:$('#ib2').val(), 
mygender2:$('#ibi3').val(),
```

and edit the PHP to:

```
$var2=$_POST['mygender1']; 
$var3=$_POST['mygender2'];
```

while you can technically send multiple form variables with the same name to the server, you need to declare them to PHP using input names suffixed with [] like "mygender[]" so that PHP reads them into an array. In your case, it would be simpler to make the edits suggested above.

Comment: thank you so much for the valuable help.. code is running well, but problem is that ,i have a one column for the gender and one for the language and ,but according to above code i think i have to create two column to insert seprately     "mygender1" and "mygender2". but i want to insert in the single column either "mygender1" or "mygender2",which one will select the user.  so what i have to do if i take a third variable as     $var4=$var2.$var3; then both gender will be inserted into the same column

Comment: Your original code is inserting the gender variable(s) in two columns so I just followed what you already had. It sounds like you figured out how to modify it to what you needed. If you like my answer, please mark it as accepted. Thanks.